# Insert input into list by the name of the menu, and then calculating its price after selecting the items

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

I wanted a create a function in Python where the user inputs the name of the menu and then it returns it in their order. After they are finished with ordering, the function would then calculate the price. My problem is I typed "Apple", but it came back empty. Is there anyway I could get around this? Any assistance is appreciated.

Here is the function:

```
menu = [{"Menu":"Apple","Price":9.00},{"Menu":"Banana","Price":5.00}], my_order = [], userInput = 0

try:
    userInput = input("Enter item menu name that you want to select >> ") except ValueError:
    print("Item does not exist.") if userInput in menu:
    print("The item is in the list") else:
    print("The item is not in the list. Please choose a different item.") while userInput != "Stop" or userInput != "stop":
    print(f"Available menu: {menu}")
    userInput = input("Do you want to add the item from the menu? If so please type appropriate item menu name. If no please type Stop. >> ")
    if userInput == "Stop" or userInput == "stop":
        print("The program has ended no more items will be added.")
        print(f"Your order: {my_order}")
        break
    elif userInput not in menu:
        print("Item does not exist in the list, try another item.")
        print(f"Your order: {my_order}")
        continue
    else:
        menu["Menu"] = userInput
        my_order.append(userInput)
        print(f"Your order: {my_order}")
        continue
```

Comment: Does your code run successfully? When I try it, it gives me a SyntaxError (because of the weird try/except).

Comment: This doesn't look like valid Python at all. There's line breaks and indentation missing all over the place. Since these are syntactically meaningful we can't reproductive the program you wrote from what you wrote here and hence also can't relative your problem. Voting to close as irreproducible - but that can be reverted at any time

Answer (score 0):

The way you use a dictionary is to have a key and a value related to it, in this  case your menu dictionary should be {"item":price}.
That way if you want to know the price of an Apple yo do

```
print(menu["Apple"])
```

Did not understand why the Try/except in this case.

```
menu = {"Apple" : 9.00, "Banana" : 5.00}
my_order = []
userInput = ""

while userInput != "Stop" or userInput != "stop":
    print(f"Available menu: {menu}")
    userInput = input("Do you want to add the item from the menu? If so please type appropriate item menu name. If no please type Stop. >> ")
    if userInput == "Stop" or userInput == "stop":
        print("The program has ended no more items will be added.")
        print(f"Your order: {my_order}")
        break
    elif userInput not in menu:
        print("Item does not exist in the list, try another item.")
        print(f"Your order: {my_order}")
        continue
    else:
        my_order.append(userInput)
        print(f"Your order: {my_order}")
        continue
```

I let you continue calculating the total for the bill.